# Is instantiating a class using `new $className()` an issue by any means? Should I use it instead of `ReflectionClass::newInstance`?

Tags: php, reflection

There are a few times, when dealing with something like a service container, where I have to instantiate a class, but I get the full class name from a configuration file. An example, much like the symfony container:

```
myService:
    class: "Vendor\Namespace\ClassName"
    arguments: [...]
```

Now, inside my container, I'm left with a choice: I can either instantiate this class using the following snippet, which makes use of this PHP strange feature that is evaluating the class name in runtime:

```
$service = new $className(...$evaluatedArguments);
```

Or I can instantiate it using Reflection:

```
$reflectionClass = new \ReflectionClass($className);
$service = $reflectionClass->newInstance($evaluatedArguments);
```

The latter is much more clear on what it's doing, and is, at the moment, my preferred method. However, since $className is not user input (is loaded from a .yaml file which works as an app configuration file), I can't find a reason not to use the first snippet other than readability.

It looks really sketchy, but I can't think of any technical/security reasons not to use it, and it *does* save some memory (I don't have to instantiate a \ReflectionClass) and is far less verbose.

My question: is using `new $className` an issue by any means?

**Disclaimer, because I know people like to get offtopic: I'm not building a Service Container. Do not advice me to use Pimple or some other DiC instead of addressing the question, this is just an example for didatic purposes.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`new $className()` is [officially supported PHP syntax](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php#language.oop5.basic.new) for instantiating a class with a variable name. Period. It works. There are no caveats. There's no reason to invoke the overhead of `ReflectionClass` for a simple object instantiation.

Comment: How would a transpiler (like facebook's HPHPc) deal with such bizarre feature? C++ checks if the class is instantiable in compile time (as opposed to PHP being in runtime), and such syntactic sugar would surely break compatibility, right? I mean, I'm not planning on using HPHPc or anything, but that would be, *technically*, a very minor downside of not using Reflection, if you think about it.

Comment: HPHPc is deprecated in favor of HHVM. But the same question applies, how would a JIT compiler deal with this?

Comment: I have no idea. *It's an officially supported feature of PHP.* If alternative PHP implementations choose not to support it, that's their problem. Whatever language they compile down to is pretty irrelevant, there's some way to handle that one way or another if the implementer chooses to. Don't get lost in the technical details. The question is: is this supported syntax by your chosen runtime or not?

Comment: So far, I had been using Reflection to instantiate everthing. I think you just convinced me not to. I guess it's refactoring time. Thank you.